# Cannot run program on public desktop Windows

Tags: windows

I have a software that i want to share for everyone login to the pc. So i install by user Administrator and copy the Desktop shortcut to Public Desktop. In some PCs it work but in some PCs when login by normal user and i double click to the program on Desktop (Share by Public Desktop) it not running but also not show any errors. Is there any where in Windows i can check log to see why it not running ?

Comment: Did the install run fine on the admin and did the program run as admin as well?
You can check the event viewer to see if there are any application or windows errors.
Also would check to see if the application itself has an error log

Comment: Hi Ed B, yes the install run fine on the admin. Thanks for your suggest i will try tocheck event viewer.

Answer (score 2):

Applications are generally responsible for logging there own errors.  Depending on the type of program and how the program set up error logging you maybe able to find some information.

First I would ensure the program is not running in the background.  You can do this by checking the task manager (ctrl+shift+esc) and looking for the program executable name.  Sometimes programs start but do not load the user interface.

After that I would look into the program itself.  If the program is logging errors they can normally be found in a log file in the install or data directory of the program.  These paths will vary however can normally be found by viewing the properties of the link to the program.  It should have a target field that will take you to the directory of the application.

If the program is not well documented than you may have to dig around to find them.  They are normally plain text files but may not be saved as a .txt

You could also check the event viewer in windows.  Depending on how the program is failing this may give you some information, or if the programmer decided to use the event log to log errors.

**Updated**

If you are only having this problem when using a standard user vs admin it is probably due to user permissions.  The folder used by the program is most likely installed in or attempting to access a folder that the standard user account lacks access to.

Comment: HI Ed B, permission also a good way to try. I will try and inform you if it success